# Using findall with multiple criteria

Tags: julia

The following code finds the indexes in the 50th column of p where the value is equal to 1.

```
findall(p[:,50].== 1)
```

But suppose I was interested in screening for multiple criteria. For example, if I was also interested in the indexes where the value is 0.5. I have tried the following in that case, but something goes wrong:

```
findall(p[:,50].== 1 | p[:,50].== 0.5)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're forgetting to dot the `|` operator. But you also need to use parens:

```
findall((p[:,50].== 1) .| (p[:,50].== 0.5))
```

But still, this is a bit wasteful, since you are making two copies of the same column, and are allocating five intermediate vectors that you don't need. You should try to use a predicate function to avoid this, like e.g. here:

```
findall(x->x in (0.5, 1.0), p[:,50])
```

or

```
findall(x->x==0.5||x==1, p[:,50])
```

On top of this, you can use `view` to avoid allocations due to `p[:,50]`:

```
findall(x->x==0.5||x==1, view(p, :,50))
```